# ASP.NET MVC4 display modes not loading TypeScript output

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application created using the Internet template.  In this project I have two layout files in the Views/Shared folder, _Layout.chsmtl and _Layout.Mobile.cshtml.  In each of these files I am loading different scripts compiled from TypeScript. In _Layout.cshtml I have

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js?43")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in _Layout.Mobile.cshtml,

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MobileApp.js?2")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

app.js and mobileapp.js are created based on the following settings in the project file:

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; -out scripts\app.js scripts\app.ts -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" /> 
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot; -out scripts\mobileapp.js scripts\mobileapp.ts  -target ES5 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

The application runs correctly in Internet Explorer 9.  However, when I run in in Opera Mobile, it appears as though mobileapp.js is not being loaded as its constructor which just displays an alert is not being called.  This is the TypeScript code for MobileApp.js.

```
 export class MobileApp extends AppBase {                                  

        constructor () { 
            super(null, null)                
              alert("mobile page loading ...?");
        }      
    }
```

I also have the following message written to the application logs each time I refresh the Index page on Opera Mobile:

```
ERROR 2013-01-24 09:39:57,233 172979ms MvcApplication         Application_Error  - ASP.global_asax
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist.
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)
   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the constructor to run, you have to instantiate the class. For example:

var Test = new MobileApp();